# Dynamic SQL with variable number of table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic

My table `icdClm` is a junction table between a table with person demographics and another table that lists various codes of interest related to that person.  I'd like to be able to join these tables a variable number of times.  I'm not interested in the other table involved in the relationship because of simplicity's sake at this point.  I want a `while loop` to help generate the query (if there is a better way I'm open to a different implementation.)

Below is the desired output if the query were to run twice (two times for the two derived tables).

```
select distinct x1.patid
from
(
select ic.patid
    from icdClm as ic
    where ic.icd like '123%'
) x1 inner join 
(
select ic.patid
    from icdClm as ic
    where ic.icd like '456%'
)x2 on x1.patid=x2.patid
inner join 
(
select ic.patid
    from icdClm as ic
    where ic.icd like '789%'

) x3 on x1.patid=x3.patid
```

notice that they alias for the derived tables increases by 1 each time.  Now for my code.  This code does not generate an error, but I left it running for over 10 minutes and no results had yet been returned.  Eventually, I would like to make another stored procedure dependent on this one that asks you the number of derived tables you want and then fills in the `where ic.icd like '123%'` with parameters inputted from the user, but first things first: what is not working with the below query?

```
declare 
@x int
,@y int
,@sql nvarchar(1000)

select 
@x=1
,@y=3
,@sql =
'select distinct x1.patid
from
(
select ic.patid
    from icdClm as ic
    where ic.icd like ''123%''
) x1'
while @x < @y
begin;
set @sql=@sql+ 
'inner join 
(
    select ic.pati
    from icdClm as ic
    where ic.icd like ''456%''
) x1 on x'+CAST(@y as CHAR(10))+'.patid=x1.patid'
set @y=@y+1
end;
print @sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while @x < @y
begin;

set @y=@y+1
end;
```

`@y` is what is incremented so this loop will either never execute (because y is less than x) or it will be an infinite loop*  because `@y` will always be larger than `@x`

perhaps you meant `@x=@x+1`

*You'll probably get an in integer overflow eventually

Comment: you are correct, it was @x that should've been incremented because duh! it'd be an infinite loop otherwise.  now that the query actually runs i can see a made a couple of other mistakes, but this is the crux of my problem.  gracias, senior frix.

Comment: :) as an aside I would go with AND in the join clause rather than inline views `icdClm x1 INNER JOIN icdClm x2 on x1.patid=x2.patid and x1.icd like ''123%'' ...` but I'm not sure that makes things better

Comment: that was how i thought about doing it first, but this way seemed to be easier when i was hashing it out.  i'll do some tests and whichever one is faster i'll roll with.

Comment: One other option is to do something in this form `select patid from icdClm WHERE icd like ''123%'' Or icd like ''456%'' GROUP BY patid HAVING count(icd) = 2` then you only have to change the WHERE and HAVING clauses

Comment: that's a neat idea too. . i'll have to play around with that as well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are tying to do an and condition of multiple terms.
If you use Intersect then you don't need unique names.
I do this but I build it up in C#.
Sorry for lack of SP example.

```
select patid
    from icdClm 
    where icd like '123%'
Intersect
select patid
    from icdClm 
    where icd like '456%'
```

[EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

I found Intersect to be efficient.
With more than 5 joins I had a problem with query optimizer getting what I called defensive and producing poor response time WITH MY DATA.
Intersect does it one at a time in a brute force manner and that may or may not be good for your data.
Since your like does not have a wild card at the beginning it may use an index.

Comment: hmm..this is interesting, i have almost never used intersect and I didn't know that you didn't have to keep different aliases.

Comment: fighting with getting the aliases right (something that i'm still tinkering with) is why i chose to use the pared-down version of what i want the final query to be.  i'll see how this performs with my data, but regardless, this is a nice little tidbit to keep in my back pocket.